# In PHP cc email, how to use group email address instead of too many comma separate emails of outlook

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have created a group in Outlook it's group id name is 'php@domain.com', which have 5 member in that group.

So i want to send mail to this group in CC.I am using 'php@domain.com' group id name in CC but no any member is receiving any mail.

```
$emp_email = $row["email"];
$msg = "test";
$subject = 'Happy Birthday!!';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: php@******.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: From Name <info@******.com>";
$sentmail = mail($emp_email, $subject, $msg, $headers);

here $emp_email is receiving mail but there is no any action in CC.
```

Comment: Have you tried to send a mail with this php script to *one* of the 5 members directly? Have you tried to send a mail using Outlook to *php@domain.com*?

Comment: Yes, directly to members working fine.

Comment: So when mailing by the script works fine to the members you know that it is neither a php nor a programming problem. It is a Outlook/Exchange/Mail configuration problem - which should not be posted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Groupid is a one unique from multiple cc. So PHP can not understand the group id.
you must have to use array in cc.

Answer (score 0):

This group id you can use only for outlook. PHP can't understand this. You should send array in CC.